# forecast subset function is not accessible via :: notation

Tags: r, function, scope

Consider this MWE and it outputs:

```r
forecast::subset(forecast::woolyrnq, start = 0 , end = 10)
# Error: 'subset' is not an exported object from 'namespace:forecast'

forecast:::subset(forecast::woolyrnq, start = 0 , end = 10)
# Error: object 'subset' not found

library(forecast)
subset(forecast::woolyrnq, start = 0 , end = 10)
#      Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
# 1964                6172
# 1965 6709 6633 6660 6786
# 1966 6800 6730 6765 6720
# 1967 7133
```

in my mind all three calls should work and the first one is the preferred way for use in an R-Package, which I'd like to go with.

Do you have any idea why I can't access the `subset` function via the `::` notation?

Comment: It should be `forecast:::subset.ts` there is no subset. subset is a generic base function.

Comment: `subset()` is a generic that has several methods.  The class of `forecast::woolyrnq` is `ts`, so when that gets passed to `subset()` the function looks for `subset.ts()`, which is in forecast, though it isn't exported.  Look at `forecast:::subset.ts`.

Comment: `forecast:::subset.ts` does work (thank you), but it still feels rather hacky.

Comment: It is not hacky, there is no need to use `forecast:::subset.ts()` after `library(forcast)` is loaded, just use `subset()`. Read about generic functions.